# excel vba- Traverse Column and display message box if value greater than *

Tags: excel, vba

i got the vba code to display msgbox by checking one value.
If Range("AH4").Value Then
MsgBox "tablespace greater than 95"

but i want to check a whole column of about 50 values and i want a looping code that traverses through the whole column and displays a msgbox if any of the value is greater than 95.
     A                    B                  C            D
1  Tablespace   Total Size(Mb)  Total Free(MB)  PCT_USED
2  MONITOR      100                  99 1
3  PSAPSR3          73,940                 3,992    94.6
4  PSAPSR3702   84,960                24,391    71.29
5  PSAPSR3USR   40                   16 61
6  PSAPUNDO     9,260                  9,221    0
7  SYSAUX       760              51.3125    93
8  SYSTEM       1,470                   9.75    99

Now i want to refine the solution given by chris. 
1. I want my msgbox should display the actual value of the cell it finds greater than 95 under PCT_USED.
2. And that msgbox should display the name of the corresponding tablespace under the column A(i have freezed this column in my excel sheet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to loop for this.

Try

```
Sub TestRange()
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = [F1:F10]  ' <-- adjust to your requirements
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng) > 95 Then
        MsgBox "tablespace greater than 95"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: you might want to change that to accommodate a variable length column

Comment: Thank you chris...it worked perfectly on my system.Gr8 work

Comment: Now i want to refine the solution given by chris. 1. I want my msgbox should display the actual value of the cell it finds greater than 95 under PCT_USED. 2. And that msgbox should display the name of the corresponding tablespace under the column A(i have freezed this column in my excel sheet).

Answer (score 0):

what about using a `for each` loop ....

```
Sub CheckInColumn()
Dim TestCell As Range

    For Each TestCell In [E1].EntireColumn.Cells
        ' break on first find
        If TestCell > 95 Then
            MsgBox "Co-coo"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next TestCell
End Sub
```

Instead of [E1] you could use `Selection` to check the column where your curser is currently positioned.

`For Each` loops are usually faster than discrete `For ... Next` loops.